# sfdisk won't change partition type

Tags: server, partitioning

I'm trying to change the partition type with the following command :

```
sudo sfdisk --change-id /dev/sdb 2 fd
```

However, I get the following error :

```
sfdisk: /dev/sdb: partition 2: failed to set partition type
```

This is how my drives look like :

[image]

Any idea how to solve this ?

I have one disk with ubuntu server. Everything installed and configured, which took me a lot of time. Now I want to add a disc and create a RAID1 array ... without losing my system on disk 1. = lot's of troubles. There are plenty of guides out there, but none of them in case you are bound to an uefi partition. So I'm doing some tests with a VM in order to accomplish this. This is my grand masterplan : (which might be stupid)

1 clone SDA to SDB as exact copies, each with own efi partition 2 convert SDB2 to a raid linux partition = md0 , degraded 3 point grub config to md0 instead of sda2 (on both drives efi partition) 4 convert and add SDA2 to raid array

That's the short version. In step 2, I need first to change the partition type to raid.I'm partly following this guide ;

https://www.considerednormal.com/2016/10/configuring-software-raid1-after-installation-of-ubuntu-16/

In order to setup raid, I must set the partition type to FD

Comment: I have no idea about what you're trying to do or why but maybe this helps: https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2017/05/sfdisk-examples/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to change the partition type of this partition, see the following:

The `sfdisk`-command `--change-id` is deprecated and you should use `--part-type` instead.

From `man sfdisk`:

```
--part-type device partition-number [type]
              Change the partition type.  If type is not specified, then print
              the current partition type.  The type  argument  is  hexadecimal
              for  MBR,  or  a  GUID  for GPT.  For backward compatibility the
              options -c and --id have the same meaning as this one.
```

As you use GPT `sfdisk` expects a `GUID` and not a `dos partition type`.

You can find the GUID for the different partition types here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table

You have to replace `fd` (which would be valid if you use dos partition table) with it's counterpart for GPT, so the correct command is

```
sudo sfdisk --part-type /dev/sdb 2 A19D880F-05FC-4D3B-A006-743F0F84911E
```

And here another interesting link:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1183234

In addition you should also change the UUID's of the cloned file-systems. When the system boots it will try to mount the Efi System Partition and the OS-partition using UUID's, the first partition found with the UUID used in `/etc/fstab` will be mounted and you can not be sure which of the two partitions with the same UUID is that.

To change the UUID of a partition use something like

```
tune2fs -U UUID /dev/sdb2
```

where `UUID` is a UUID of your choice or the keyword `random` to generate a new random UUID. Take a look at `man tune2fs`.

Comment: --part-type gives exactly the same error as --change-id ... So that doesn't help

Comment: You have to use a GUID, not the dos partition identifier `fd`, in your command replace `fd` with `A19D880F-05FC-4D3B-A006-743F0F84911E` which is the GUID for a linux-raid.

Comment: But I think this action will render the partition unusable, try at your own risk. I don't think it will have any negative effect with the other partition `sda2`.

Comment: Yes, using the --part-type + the GUID seems to work! Thank you...

Comment: You can also use **uuidgen** to generate various types of UUID's.

Comment: Link to correct part of wikipedia, listing the GUIDs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Partition_type_GUIDs

Comment: Here you have another link: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GPT_fdisk#Partition_type